# How can I select my entire party?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-enhanced

I've just downloaded Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition on my mobile device, and I'm really enjoying it, but it's gotten rather tedious having to select and move each individual party member. On the PC version of Baldur's Gate one can press the <kbd>=</kbd> key, I believe, to select the entire party. Is there a way to do this on the mobile edition?

Comment: On the PC version there's a button in the bottom-right of the screen. Do you have something similar on mobile? http://imgur.com/NHhRPWE

Comment: @Studoku Yes, I do.

Comment: That should do it. I'll post it as an answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: On the PC pressing zero will also select the whole party.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a "select all" button in the bottom-right corner of your screen- it looks like 3 people surrounded by a box.
[image: Selection box]

Clicking it will select the entire party.